# Exception thrown from within orElseGet is wrapped with UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: exception, groovy

In one of our service classes, we are throwing an exception to deal with in the controller. However, in one of the cases, the exception is from within `orElseGet`.

```
def function() throws CustomException {
  try {
            ProjectAssignment assignment = workspaceRepositoryService.getWorkspaceMembership(command.assigneeEmail, workspaceId).map {
                createOrUndelete(it, project, command.assigneeRole, createdBy)
            }.orElseGet {
                ...

                try {
                    Invitation invitation = workspaceService.inviteUserToWorkspace(command.assigneeEmail, workspace, createdBy) // throws CustomException
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw e // getting CustomException
                }

                ...
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e // getting UndeclaredThrowableException wrapping CustomException
        }
}
```

The exception thrown inside `orElseGet` is wrapped with `UndeclaredThrowableException`. Is there a way to preserve the type of thrown exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
...
catch( UndeclaredThrowableException e){
    throw e.getCause()
}
catch(Exception e){
    throw e
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: catch(e){ throw e.cause?:e }